# Migrate WHM sites to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpanel, whm

I have few PHP/MySql sites hosted on WHM/cPanel reseller hosting account. I am looking to move to AWS. All these sites are very low traffic and low bandwidth. I am hoping to migrate and save some money in hosting fees. Not that I pay too much right now, I just like the idea of pay as much as you use.

Since sysops is not my core strengths, I am looking for a guide as such that will help me transfer these sites over to an EC2 instance, stuff like install mysql, php etc and have DNS point to different hosts for different sites.

Any pointers to achieve this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to contact your one of the server admin as you will have to install and configured apache, Mysql, PHP and DNS on your server, Once server setup is completed then you need to migrate your all web files from your cPanel account to your AWS server, You can migrate that files through FTP account. And for the mysql you can download your mysql databases backup file through phpmyadmin.

Once your site is migrated, Create name server on your AWS server and update that IP's to your domain register end,

Comment: I wish there was some sort of automation script to do most of these or some of the core steps. Thanks for the instructions.